# Plot this function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

[Link to function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Nho.jpg)

Plot the function above within the range (x1,x2) is an element of [-1,1] x [-1,1].

I have tried [myself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qVRL.jpg) but I get this which I'm not sure it is correct. Since this is a quadratic equation and I was expecting some curve.

Comment: There are two variables, then you should not be expecting a curve.

Comment: Just like z=x^2+y^2, the plot of your function should be a surface, too.

Comment: @Statham, is my plot correct then? I need to use point-wise multiplication to calculate the function plot.

Comment: I am new in matlab too, but I think your x-range is too big in the plot

Comment: @Statham, in order to generate some values for the function. I incremented the range from -1 to 1 by 0.01. Could that be the reason why the x-range is too big?

Answer (score 1):

As Statham suggested in the comment you should expect a surface, not a curve, and should prepare your data accordingly. If you want get a plot of the function you presented, this is an example of how:

```
w0=0.01; w1=0.4; w2=-0.2; w3=0.01; w4=0.2; w5=1;

x1=linspace(-1,1,21);
x2=linspace(-1,1,21);
[X1,X2]=meshgrid(x1,x2);

Z=w0+w1*X1+w2*X2+w3*X1.^2+w4*X2.^2+w5*X1*transpose(X2);

surf(X1,X2,Z);
```

The result:
[image: surf plot result]